# Should csi-socket be cleaned up during plugin uninstallation

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, csi

I see node-driver registrar cleans up registration socket
PR: https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/node-driver-registrar/pull/61

Should csi-socket be also removed when a CSI plugin is uninstalled?

If yes, I assume this must be taken care by driver code but will there be any impacts?

I see csi-socket is used by many sidecars. So connection will get corrupted.
Could someone shed more light on this.

We were using `/var/lib/kubelet/csi-plugins` path and now want to migrate to  `/var/lib/kubelet/plugins`. When plugin is upgraded, we would like a cleanup to be done. But then I see this might be challenging.